# mysqldump error on common_schema

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I tried to take the backup of common_schema in Server version: `5.5.44 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`.

```
mysqldump -u root -p common_schema > common_schema_bkup.sql
```

I got the following error:

> "mysqldump: Got error: 1356: View 'common_schema._bare_grantee_grants'
>   references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or
>   definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them when using LOCK
>   TABLES"

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Run this query and paste the output here:  select * from common_schema.sql_grants;

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli I get this error -- ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'common_schema.sql_grants' doesn't exist

Comment: It has been deleted or you don't have access rights.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you should use [**--single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u root -p common_schema > common_schema_bkup.sql
```

Why ? According to the MySQL Documentation on mysqldump, you need the following rights:

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, and LOCK TABLES **if the `--single-transaction` option is not used**. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.
>
> To reload a dump file, you must have the same privileges needed to create each of the dumped objects by issuing CREATE statements manually.

Please note the [*common_schema is comprised of one table and 27 views*](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/data_dimension_views.html). You must have the necessary grants in order to be able to dump them, whether or not you dump with [**--single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction). This might include having the [`CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-view) and [`SHOW VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-view) grants.

## UPDATE 2015-07-24 23:09 EST

I think the problem rests with mysqldump itself. Many metacommands are written around the dump of the definitions that could be interfering with rendering output that can logically represented. [***In some cases, a mysqldump of common_schema could not be reimported***](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/issues/detail?id=31).

Your best chance would be to import common_schema from scratch. [Right from the common_schema Documentation, it says on troubleshooting installation](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/install.html):

> Since installation is merely an import act, you should only expect trouble if schema generation is unable to execute on your server.
>
> - Are you executing on a 5.0 MySQL server? This version is not supported.
> - Were errors reported during installation process?
> - What was common_schema's last message during install?
> - What is the output of SELECT * FROM common_schema.status?

Since unique metadata is not in common_schema, you should be able to reimport it rather that risk backing up with mysqldump with the possibility of not reloading it.

Comment: Okay I will try it and update but just wanted to clarify that I'm trying this with root user and it has all the privileges.

Comment: I'm getting the same error -- mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `_bare_grantee_grants`': View 'common_schema._bare_grantee_grants' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)

Comment: Please connect to MySQL and run `SELECT USER() AttemptedToLogin,CURRENT_USER() AllowedToLogin;`. What is the output ??? I just want to make sure you have full privileges.

Comment: +------------------+----------------+
| AttemptedToLogin | AllowedToLogin |
+------------------+----------------+
| root@localhost   | root@localhost |
+------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Run `SELECT COUNT(1) table_count,engine FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='common_schema' GROUP BY engine;` What is the output ???

Comment: +-------------+--------+
| table_count | engine |
+-------------+--------+
|          19 | NULL   |
|          11 | InnoDB |
|           7 | MyISAM |
+-------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: That seems strange. The documentation says common_schema should have 27 views. You only have 19. (https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/data_dimension_views.html)

Comment: What is interesting here is that the creator of common_schema is here in the DBA StackExchange. Hey, @ShlomiNoach. This is in your realm of expertise. Any ideas on how to properly mysqldump common_schema or is installation the only way ??? (I would wait for an answer from him)

Comment: Here is the author's profile : http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10090/shlomi-noach

Comment: Hope the gentleman replies.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, one of the views is lost. You should re-install common_schema. Or maybe you don't have all proper access rights - in that case, just check your rights.

Comment: I'm tryiny it from root user. It has all the rights.

Comment: Being root doesn't mean that you have all the rights: it is possible that you accidentally revoked some rights from root. But, as I said, the alternative is that you don't have that view anymore. Reinstall Common Schema.